# Check if array element starts with a certain string

Tags: bash, if-statement, for-loop

This is how my input looks like:

```
privatertid=[ "usr-11111", "usr-22222" ]
```

I am looping thru this treating it as an array and if the the string starts with `usr-`, I want to do more operations on it.

```
for i in $privatertid; do
  echo checking $i
  if [[ "$i" == usr-* ]]; then
    echo user:$i
  fi;
done
```

Control of the program never echoes `user:usr-11111` or `user:usr-22222`.

Am i not comparing the "`string starts with usr-`" correctly?

Comment: @AndriiAbramov: I have tried that but it does not work.

Comment: Use: `privatertid=( "usr-11111" "usr-22222" )` and `for i in "${privatertid[@]}"; do`

Comment: @Cyrus: Thank you. Appreciate your help.